# Stuck on checking symbols in the string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to check if the word is long enough and contains symbols `()1234567890!?_@#$%^&*.,'` only at the end of string. Conditions are next:

- The word should be more than 3 chars long without symbols. Symbol '-' count as a char
- Correct word should not contain special symbols at start and middle
  of string

I decided to use regex:

```
    def check_word(word: str) -> bool:
      m = re.match("[^()1234567890!?_@#$%^&*.,]{4,}[()1234567890!?_@#‌​$‌​%^&*.,]*", word)
      if m is not None:
         return True
      return False
    print(check_word("Hell,oo")) # False
    print(check_word("Hello,!")) # True
    print(check_word('Hello"'))  # False
```

So my question is why I'm keeping to get `True` on `print(check_word("Hell,oo")`) if in `re.match` I pointed that there shouldn't be any symbols before chars. And why `print(check_word('Hello"'))` is `True` if symbol `'"'` not even in the list?

Comment: `^[^()\d!?_@#$%^&*.,']{3,}[()\d!?_@#$%^&*.,']*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `^` and `$` to indicate the start and the end of the string. `^` is implied with `match()` as indicated in the comments, so you only need to specify `$`. Here is a an example:

```
re.match(r'[^()1234567890!?_@#‌​$‌​%^&*.,]{4,}[()1234567890!?_@#‌​$‌​%^&*.,]*$', 'Hell,oo')
```

But since you *require* that the string contains symbols, you should use `+` instead of `*` since `*` matches zero characters or more, while `+` matches one character or more. Or replace `*` with a specified number like you did with `{4,}`.

And for your question:

> And why `print(check_word('Hello"'))` is `True` if symbol `'"'` not even in the list?

It is because of `[^()1234567890!?_@#‌​$‌​%^&*.,]`. This matches any character that is **not** in this set, and `"` is not in it. To solve that, you can use **`[a-zA-Z]`** instead which matches any alphabetic English character:

```
re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]{4,}[()1234567890!?_@#‌​$‌​%^&*.,]*$', 'Hell,oo')
```

Comment: Not, `^`, since that's implied with `match`.

Comment: Also, `\w` includes digits and underscore.

Comment: Thank you. Edited accordingly.

Comment: But if I also want to make that strings only with `"-"` in the middle were True. Should I make another `re.match` like this `(r'[a-zA-Z][-][a-zA-Z]', word)` and after put it in loop?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear to me. Do you mean that you want to return `True` only if the string contains `-` in the middle between the alphabetic characters and the symbols like `Hello-!#`?

Comment: Only in the middle. For example `He-llo` or `He-llo!#`. So that function read it like a char and returns `True`

Comment: You could use something like this: `r'[a-zA-Z]+-?[a-zA-Z]+[()1234567890!?_@#‌​$‌​%^&*.,]*$'`. Note that `{4,}` is omitted here. Instead, `[a-zA-Z]+-?[a-zA-Z]+` matches one or more alphabetic characters, *possibly* followed by `-`, followed by one or more alphabetic characters. Of course you can replace `+` with `{}` if you want.

Comment: Or you can use `r'[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z]{2,}[a-zA-Z][()1234567890!?_@#‌​$‌​%^&*.,]*$'`: `[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z]{2,}[a-zA-Z]` matches an alphabetic character, followed by two or more alphabetic characters or `-`, followed by an alphabetic character. Note that with this pattern, more than one `-` may exist in the middle of the string.